# Fixed one Header of tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have eight tables with the same two rows in . My question is, can I fix the two rows of the first table, hidden the two same rows of the other tables and the other content of eight tables scrolling? I have no time to rewrite the hole code. I need an easy solution.

Here is a screenshot
[image]
Here is my Code

```html
<div style="height:65vh; overflow:auto" onupdate="set_tables_to_same_width()"> 
                        <div id="1"> 
                            <h2 id="Fixkostentitle">Fixkosten</h2>
                            <div id="cbd_table_0" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto" onchange=" refreshData()">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Fixkosten_cols" id="Fixkosten_cols" value="5">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Fixkosten_max_row" id="Fixkosten_max_row" value="2">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Fixkosten_cols_dev" id="Fixkosten_cols_dev" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Fixkosten_dropdown_count" id="Fixkosten_dropdown_count" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Fixkosten_dropdown_0" id="Fixkosten_dropdown_0" value="DE,DEU">
                                <table id="Fixkosten" class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Löschen
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Summe
                                                <div style="width:130px">
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Hinzufügen
                                                <div>
                                                    <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-addlink.svg" alt="create row" onclick="appendRow_blank([['DE','DEU']],&quot;Fixkosten&quot;)" width="20" height="20">
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th id="Fixkosten_entwicklungs_header_" colspan="3" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Entwicklung
                                                <div>
                                                    <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-addlink.svg" alt="create year" onclick='append_all_years("",0)' width="20" height="20">
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <th id="Fixkosten_betreuungs_header_" colspan="3" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Serienbetreuung/Wartung
                                                <div>
                                                    <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-addlink.svg" alt="create year" onclick='append_all_years("",1)' width="20" height="20">
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th colspan="3" id="Fixkosten_entwicklungs_header_0" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 0; top: 0px; left: 0px;" onchange='link_weeks("Fixkosten_entwicklungs_header_0")'>
                                                <input type="week" value="2019-W15" placeholder="YYYY-Wcw" style="text-align: center;width:175px" id="Fixkosten_entwicklungs_header_00L" name="Fixkosten_year">
                                                <p style="display:inline"> -- 
                                                </p>
                                                <input placeholder="YYYY-Wcw" type="week" value="2019-W20" style="text-align: center;width:175px" id="Fixkosten_entwicklungs_header_00R" name="Fixkosten_year">
                                                <p style="display:inline"> 5 | 25 | 25
                                                </p>
                                                <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-deletelink.svg" alt="delete year" onclick='delete_all_col("Fixkosten_entwicklungs_header_0")' width="20" height="20">
                                            </th>
                                            <th colspan="3" id="Fixkosten_betreuungs_header_0" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 0; top: 0px; left: 0px;" onchange='link_weeks("Fixkosten_betreuungs_header_0")'>
                                                <input type="week" placeholder="YYYY-Wcw" style="text-align: center;width:175px" id="Fixkosten_betreuungs_header_00L" name="Fixkosten_year">
                                                <p style="display:inline"> -- 
                                                </p>
                                                <input placeholder="YYYY-Wcw" type="week" style="text-align: center;width:175px" id="Fixkosten_betreuungs_header_00R" name="Fixkosten_year">
                                                <p style="display:inline"> NaN | NaN | NaN
                                                </p>
                                                <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-deletelink.svg" alt="delete year" onclick='delete_all_col("Fixkosten_betreuungs_header_0")' width="20" height="20">
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="sum" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">144,00 EUR
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Funktion
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Beschreibung
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Land
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Preis pro ME [EUR/ME]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Anzahl [ME]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Kosten [EUR]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Preis pro ME [EUR/ME]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Anzahl [ME]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Kosten [EUR]
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="Fixkosten_row_0" onchange='dependend_costs("Fixkosten_row_0")'>
                                            <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">
                                                <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-deletelink.svg" alt="delete row" onclick='deleteRow("Fixkosten_row_0");refreshData(False)' width="20" height="20"></td>
                                            <td class="sum" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">144,00 EUR</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="TextField" value="test" style="width:200px"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="TextField" value="test" style="width:200px"></td><td>
                                                <select name="Fixkosten_row_0" style="width:504.199951171875px">
                                                    <option value="0">DE
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="1" selected="selected">DEU
                                                    </option>
                                                </select></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" value="12,00 EUR/ME" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" value="12" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" value="144,00 EUR" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" readonly="readonly" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" value="0" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" readonly="readonly" lang="de-DE"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="Fixkosten_row_1" onchange='dependend_costs("Fixkosten_row_1")'>
                                            <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">
                                                <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-deletelink.svg" alt="delete row" onclick='deleteRow("Fixkosten_row_1");refreshData(False)' width="20" height="20"></td>
                                            <td class="sum" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">0,00 EUR</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="TextField" style="width:200px"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="TextField" style="width:200px"></td><td>
                                                <select name="Fixkosten_row_1" style="width:504.199951171875px">
                                                    <option value="0" selected="selected">DE
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="1">DEU
                                                    </option>
                                                </select></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="NumberInput" value="0" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" readonly="readonly" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Fixkosten_row_1" id="NumberInput" value="0" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" readonly="readonly" lang="de-DE"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                        <div id="2"> 
                            <h2 id="Lizenzkostentitle">Lizenzkosten</h2>
                            <div id="cbd_table_1" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto" onchange=" refreshData()">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Lizenzkosten_cols" id="Lizenzkosten_cols" value="6">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Lizenzkosten_max_row" id="Lizenzkosten_max_row" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Lizenzkosten_cols_dev" id="Lizenzkosten_cols_dev" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Lizenzkosten_dropdown_count" id="Lizenzkosten_dropdown_count" value="0">
                                <table id="Lizenzkosten" class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Löschen
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Summe
                                                <div style="width:130px">
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Hinzufügen
                                                <div>
                                                    <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-addlink.svg" alt="create row" onclick='appendRow_blank([],"Lizenzkosten")' width="20" height="20">
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th id="Lizenzkosten_entwicklungs_header_" colspan="3" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Entwicklung
                                                <div>
                                                    <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-addlink.svg" alt="create year" onclick='append_all_years("",0)' width="20" height="20">
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <th id="Lizenzkosten_betreuungs_header_" colspan="3" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Serienbetreuung/Wartung
                                                <div>
                                                    <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-addlink.svg" alt="create year" onclick='append_all_years("",1)' width="20" height="20">
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th colspan="3" id="Lizenzkosten_entwicklungs_header_0" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 0; top: 0px; left: 0px;" onchange='link_weeks("Lizenzkosten_entwicklungs_header_0")'>
                                                <input type="week" value="2019-W15" placeholder="YYYY-Wcw" style="text-align: center;width:175px" id="Lizenzkosten_entwicklungs_header_00L" name="Lizenzkosten_year">
                                                <p style="display:inline"> -- 
                                                </p>
                                                <input placeholder="YYYY-Wcw" type="week" value="2019-W20" style="text-align: center;width:175px" id="Lizenzkosten_entwicklungs_header_00R" name="Lizenzkosten_year">
                                                <p style="display:inline"> 5 | 25 | 25
                                                </p>
                                                <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-deletelink.svg" alt="delete year" onclick='delete_all_col("Lizenzkosten_entwicklungs_header_0")' width="20" height="20">
                                            </th>
                                            <th colspan="3" id="Lizenzkosten_betreuungs_header_0" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 0; top: 0px; left: 0px;" onchange='link_weeks("Lizenzkosten_betreuungs_header_0")'>
                                                <input type="week" placeholder="YYYY-Wcw" style="text-align: center;width:175px" id="Lizenzkosten_betreuungs_header_00L" name="Lizenzkosten_year">
                                                <p style="display:inline"> -- 
                                                </p>
                                                <input placeholder="YYYY-Wcw" type="week" style="text-align: center;width:175px" id="Lizenzkosten_betreuungs_header_00R" name="Lizenzkosten_year">
                                                <p style="display:inline"> NaN | NaN | NaN
                                                </p>
                                                <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-deletelink.svg" alt="delete year" onclick='delete_all_col("Lizenzkosten_betreuungs_header_0")' width="20" height="20">
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="sum" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">0,00 EUR
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Funktion
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Beschreibung
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Lieferant
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Anteilige Nutzung %
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Preis pro ME [EUR/ME]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Anzahl [ME]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Kosten [EUR]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Preis pro ME [EUR/ME]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Anzahl [ME]
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); position: relative; top: 0px;">Kosten [EUR]
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="Lizenzkosten_row_0" onchange='dependend_costs("Lizenzkosten_row_0")'>
                                            <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">
                                                <img src="dCBD%20aus%20Template%20%20%20Django%20site%20admin-Dateien/icon-deletelink.svg" alt="delete row" onclick='deleteRow("Lizenzkosten_row_0");refreshData(False)' width="20" height="20"></td>
                                            <td class="sum" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">0,00 EUR</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; left: 0px;">
                                                <input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="TextField" style="width:200px"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="TextField" style="width:200px"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="TextField" style="width:200px"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="TextField" style="width:272.5555419921875px"></td><td>
<input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
<input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
<input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" value="0" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" readonly="readonly" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
<input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" lang="de-DE"></td><td>
                                                <input type="text" name="Lizenzkosten_row_0" id="NumberInput" value="0" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="10" currency="true" style="width:150px" readonly="readonly" lang="de-DE"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can we please see your code?

Comment: please create a demo fiddle

Comment: I edit my question